# How do I send Request Body in Robot Framework

Tags: api, robotframework

How do I send Request Body in Robot Framework
Post request body but it gives Issue as Client Error: “Not Acceptable for url: [https://apiexample.com/demo”](https://apiexample.com/demo%E2%80%9D)

```
*** Test Cases ***
GenerateToken
    ${headers}=  create dictionary   Content-Type=application/json
    ${body}=  create dictionary    username=abc@example.in   password=abc123 // I can not pass this request body in Post session below
    #${body}=   get file  /Users/Documents/data.json   // This method works but **I don't want to use this file method**
    create session  mysession   ${base_Url}     headers=${headers}
    ${response}=    Post On Session    mysession   /demo  data=${body}   headers=${headers}
```

Comment: For creating dictionary use &{body}

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
*** Test Cases ***

GenerateToken
    ${headers}=  create dictionary   Content-Type=application/json
    ${body}=  create dictionary    username=abc@example.in   password=abc123
    create session  mysession   ${base_Url}     headers=${headers}
    ${response}=    Post On Session    mysession   /demo  json=${body}   headers=${headers}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding conversion to string for the message body helped for me. Like this:

```
    *** Test Cases ***

GenerateToken
    ${headers}=    create dictionary   Content-Type=application/json
    ${json_obj}=    create dictionary    username=abc@example.in   password=abc123
    ${body}=    Convert JSON To String    ${json_obj}
    create session    mysession    ${base_Url}     headers=${headers}
    ${response}=    Post On Session    mysession    /demo    json=${body}    headers=${headers}
```